# Laravel rewrite 2 update queries into 1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Is there a way to rewrite the following queries into 1 query?

```
$this->template->whereId($id)->update(['default' => true]);
$this->template->whereNotIn('id', $id)->update(['default' => false]);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: DB::raw only. is it acceptable for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can combine them in one MySQL query (if you're using MySQL) like so:

```
UPDATE template_table
     SET default = CASE
        WHEN id = $id THEN 1
        WHEN id <> $id THEN 0
        ELSE default = default
     END
```

And then you can use DB::raw() to send a raw query to the database.

Comment: i think `ELSE default` should be. and by ELSE is not needed

Answer (score 0):

```
DB::statement("
    UPDATE templates
    SET default = 
        CASE
            WHEN id = ? THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END
", [$id]);
```

there is NO other (Eloquent) way